# Read text file of titles into dictionary

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary

I have this text file of destinations and I need to read them into a dictionary and sort them out based on the starting place and destination.

```
JFK MCO
ORD DEN
ORD HOU
DFW PHX
JFK ATL
ORD DFW
ORD PHX
ATL HOU
DEN PHX
PHX LAX
JFK ORD
DEN LAS
DFW HOU
ORD ATL
LAS LAX
ATL MCO
HOU MCO
LAS PHX
STL PDX
```

Expected Results:

```
{'JKF' : {'MCO', 'ATL','ORD'}, 'ORD' : {'DEN' , 'HOU' , 'DFW' , 'PHX' , 'ATL' ........}}
```

The main ideas is that the starting place is on the left and the destination is on the right. Group the destinations to each starting place.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can iterate through the lines, split the lines and use `dict.setdefault` to store the destinations into a dict of sets with the originating place as the keys:

```
d = {}
with open('file.txt') as file:
    for line in file:
        orig, dest = line.split()
        d.setdefault(orig, set()).add(dest)
```

`d` becomes:

```
{'JFK': {'ORD', 'ATL', 'MCO'}, 'ORD': {'DEN', 'HOU', 'ATL', 'DFW', 'PHX'}, 'DFW': {'PHX', 'HOU'}, 'ATL': {'MCO', 'HOU'}, 'DEN': {'PHX', 'LAS'}, 'PHX': {'LAX'}, 'LAS': {'PHX', 'LAX'}, 'HOU': {'MCO'}, 'STL': {'PDX'}}
```

Comment: Thank you so much. This was the best solution!

Answer (score 3):

This is done very easily using very basic for loop and a [dictdefaultdict](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict)

```
from collections import defaultdict
d = defaultdict(set)
with open("filename.txt", "r") as f:
    for line in f: 
        start, place = line.split()
        d[start].add(place)
```

It can also be done using the [csv](https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html) module

```
from collections import defaultdict
import csv

d = defaultdict(set)
with open("filename.txt", "r") as f:
    r = csv.reader(f, delimiter=' ')
    for start, place in r: d[start].add(place)
```

Of course, this results in a `defaultdict`, although you can still use it the same as a dict, if you want `d` to be a true dict after use `d = dict(d)`.

Comment: the line `d[start] = place` means that you will only have the last `place` of the `start` as it will keep overwriting the `value` if the `key` is already in the dictionary `d`.

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
depart_place = ['JFK', 'ORD', 'ORD', 'DFW', 'JFK']
destination = ['MCO', 'DEN', 'HOU', 'PHX', 'ATL']

place_dict = {}

for place, dest in zip(depart_place, destination):
    if place in place_dict:
        place_dict[place].add(dest)
    else:
        place_dict[place] = {dest}
```

So, essentially, we are iterating through tuples of departing place and destination `(place, dest)` resulting from `zip(depart_place, destination)`. Then, we check if the `place` is already in the dictionary, we append the `destination` to it or else, we create a new `key-value` pair for the `place`